# how to call the function that was using mysql keywords as parameters by the criteria query?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I am using mysql with jpa specification query.
I want to know how can i call the function that was using mysql keywords as parameters.

Here is the example:

```
select * from schema3.countries order by convert(name using GBK);
```

The `convert` method using the `using` and `GBK` keywords as paramters.

I want to call the `convert` function by the criteria  query.

I tried the below but it does not working for me.

```
Expression expression = join.get(Country_.NAME);
                Expression orderExpression = builder.function(
                        "convert",
                        String.class,
                        expression,
                        builder.literal("USING GBK")
                );
```

and

```
Path path = join.get(Country_.NAME);

                String countryNameAlias = path.getAlias();
                Expression orderExpression = builder.function(
                        "convert",
                        String.class,
                        builder.literal(countryNameAlias + " USING GBK")
                );
```

The variable `countryNameAlias` is null so it`s not working.

Here is the error :

```
Hibernate: select expert0_.id as id1_14_, expert0_.code as code2_14_, expert0_.created_at as created_3_14_, expert0_.expert_information as expert_i4_14_, expert0_.meta_data_of_the_expert_information as meta_dat5_14_, expert0_.motherland as motherla8_14_, expert0_.number_of_applications as number_o6_14_, expert0_.updated_at as updated_7_14_, JSON_EXTRACT(expert0_.expert_information, '$.basicInformation.birthDate') as formula4_, case
           when
               JSON_EXTRACT(expert0_.expert_information, '$.basicInformation.gender') = 'MALE'
            then 0
else 1 end as formula5_, JSON_EXTRACT(expert0_.expert_information, '$.basicInformation.nameEN') as formula6_, convert(JSON_EXTRACT(expert0_.expert_information, '$.basicInformation.nameZH') using GBK) as formula7_ from expert expert0_ left outer join expert_application_record expertappl1_ on expert0_.id=expertappl1_.expert_id left outer join countries country2_ on expert0_.motherland=country2_.id where expertappl1_.latest=? order by convert(?) desc limit ?
2019-11-05 18:58:41.281 TRACE 15252 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BOOLEAN] - [true]
2019-11-05 18:58:41.281 TRACE 15252 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null USING GBK]
2019-11-05 18:58:41.282  WARN 15252 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2019-11-05 18:58:41.282 ERROR 15252 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') desc limit 10' at line 5
2019-11-05 18:58:41.285 ERROR 15252 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') desc limit 10' at line 5
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:960) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1019) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
```

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@formula` anotation cannot work with native query.
Here is the link: [I am the link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449118/hibernate-defaultentityaliases-raises-nullpointerexception)

I am not familiar the jpa too much but here is the better solution than using the `@Formula` annotation.

First you need to create a custom Dialect 
Here is the example:

```
public class CustomMariaDB53Dialect extends MariaDB53Dialect {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomMariaDB53Dialect.class);

    public CustomMariaDB53Dialect() {
        super();
}
```

And then register a function to the Dialect
Here is the code:

```
public class CustomMariaDB53Dialect extends MariaDB53Dialect {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomMariaDB53Dialect.class);

    public CustomMariaDB53Dialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("convertEncode", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "convert(?1 using ?2)"));
    }
}
```

The first param of the `registerFunction` method is function name.

The second is a implement of `SqlFunction`

The `?1` and `?2` means the args of the function
So the function template is `convert(?1 using ?2)`

After above stpes done.

You should tell the hibernate you are using a new Dialect

The path of the config is `hibernate.dialect`

Here is the example:

```
hibernate.dialect=xxx.xxx.CustomMariaDB53Dialect
```

If you are using spring boot jpa.

Here is the config:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: xxx.xxx.CustomMariaDB53Dialect
```

The last step is to use the function in your query.

Here is the example:

```
Expression<String> countryName = builder().function(
                        "convertEncode", 
                        String.class,
                        join.get(Country_.NAME),
                        builder().literal("gbk")
                );

                return direction.isDescending() ? builder().desc(countryName ) : builder().asc(countryName );
```

Here is the final sql:

```
order by convert(expert0_.name_zh using ?) asc limit ?
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the sql to below :

```
select *, convert(name using GBK) as nameGBK from schema3.countries order by nameGBK;
```

So the next question is how to add computed column to the selection.
We can add a column to the country model.
The field name is `nameGBK` and use the @Formula annotation;
here is the code

```
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Formula("convert(name using GBK)")
    private String nameGBK;
```

and then in the criteria query we can order by the `nameGBK`.
Here is the code:

```
builder.desc(join.get(Country_.NAME_GBK));
```

But the jpa I am using cannot parse the keywords `using` and  `GBK` so we must extend
the Dialect of which you are using and register the keywords.

Here is the code:

```
public class CustomMariaDB53Dialect extends MariaDB53Dialect {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomMariaDB53Dialect.class);

    public CustomMariaDB53Dialect() {
        super();
        registerKeyword("using");
        registerKeyword("USING");
        registerKeyword("GBK");
        registerKeyword("gbk");
    }
}
```

And change the config to tell the hibernate you are using a new Dialect.
If you are using spring data jpa.
Then here is the config:

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://dev:13306/schema3?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=GMT%2B8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&nullCatalogMeansCurrent=true
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    initialization-mode: always
  liquibase:
    enabled: false
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        order_inserts: true
        #here to tell the hibernate you are using a new dialect.
        dialect: com.hide.hide.CustomMariaDB53Dialect
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 100
```