# How to use mysql convert function in JPA Specification?

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

`JPA` Order By with Character Set Issue.

I use `spring-data-jpa` and `mysql 5.7`. My db character set is `utf8mb4` for I need store emoji in table.

Here is my table:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                 | varchar(50)  | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| name               | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| content            | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| status             | varchar(20)  | NO   | MUL | DEFAULT           |                             |
| type               | varchar(50)  | NO   | MUL | DEFAULT           |                             |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I want to select item and order by name with Chinese character order. Item name can be emoji and Chinese string.

I can do this if use native sql :

```
select * from item where name like ? order by convert(name using gbk);
```

Is it possible to use `convert(name using gbk)` in JPA Specification?

Comment: I doubt that JPA supports this, but why not just use a native query?  JPA still plugs into native queries very well (if you check the documentation on that).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to call the function that was using mysql keywords as parameters by the criteria query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709930/how-to-call-the-function-that-was-using-mysql-keywords-as-parameters-by-the-crit)